# jQuery fire multiple times

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am tring to print list of rows code is working but it shows the print page two times.

What is wrong with my jQuery code to be fired multiple times when printing page.

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   $(document).on('click','.print-btn',function () {
      // $('#print-area').printThis();
       $("#print-area").printThis({
           debug: false,               // show the iframe for debugging
           importCSS: true,            // import parent page css
           importStyle: false,         // import style tags
           printContainer: true,       // print outer container/$.selector
           loadCSS: "",                // path to additional css file - use an array [] for multiple
           pageTitle: "Airports List",              // add title to print page
           removeInline: false,        // remove inline styles from print elements
           removeInlineSelector: "*",  // custom selectors to filter inline styles. removeInline must be true
           printDelay: 333,            // variable print delay
           header: null,               // prefix to html
           footer: null,               // postfix to html
           base: false,                // preserve the BASE tag or accept a string for the URL
           formValues: true,           // preserve input/form values
           canvas: false,              // copy canvas content
           doctypeString: '...',       // enter a different doctype for older markup
           removeScripts: false,       // remove script tags from print content
           copyTagClasses: false,      // copy classes from the html & body tag
           beforePrintEvent: null,     // function for printEvent in iframe
           beforePrint: null,          // function called before iframe is filled
           afterPrint: null            // function called before iframe is removed
       });
   });

});
```

Comment: thank you so much for helping me as fast as you did you solved my problem thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `off()`.

`.off()` method removes event handlers that were attached previously.

So in your case:

```
$(document).off().on('click','.print-btn',function () {
//Codes
});
```